# cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable returns null on getSlug()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, slug

Trying out [cviebrokc/eloquent-sluggable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) I've tried accessing the Eloquent through a blade view, echoing out the slug of a post to link to. The database table, using sqlite, has a slug column but getting the posts through Eloquent and dumping a `$post->getSlug()` returns `NULL`. It's setup as following:

In my blade view:

```
@foreach (Posts::get() as $post)
    {{ var_dump( $post->getSlug() ) }}
@endforeach
```

And in my Posts.php model:

```
<?php
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;

class Posts extends Eloquent implements SluggableInterface{

    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = array(
        'build_from' => 'title',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
    );
}
```

Should I assign it as a new instance, if so, how? Or how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that `$post->getSlug()` only gets the slug field designated. To get the slug, save it to database and show it to the user you need to create the slug with `sluggify()` and then store it in the database yourself. Doing it from model it would look like this

```
//Check if slug is empty and generate if it isn't
public function slugCheck()
{
    if(empty($this->getSlug())) // Is slug empty
    {
        $this->sluggify();      // Create slug
        $this->save();          // Save slug to database
    }
    return $this->getSlug();    // return the slug to echo out
}
```